# It made a pleasant change not having to work. (the identity of 'having')

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

> It made a pleasant change not having to work.

What's the identity of 'having' here? Gerund or Present participle?

Comment: ***having to*** here is syntactically irrelevant, as is the "fronting" of the main verb *(**made**)*. You could just as well analyse ***Not working made a pleasant change***. Which to my mind looks much the same as ***Swimming is a good exercise***.

Comment: Most modern grammarians don't distinguish between participles and gerunds.  If they don't find the difference to be important, why do you?  What is the problem that you have with this sentence that would be solved if you knew the identity of "having".

Comment: If 'not having to work' is a gerund, then 'not having to work' could replace the subject 'it' which is a fake subject. But I feel that 'it' in the front triggers 'curiosity' of the listener.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is rather odd, and probably badly punctuated.  I suspect that there should have been a comma after "change", and the structure is similar to

> It was very scary, the ghost.

This kind of structure is common enough in speech.  The speaker begins with a pronoun but then realises that the reference of the pronoun is unclear, provides the reference in a fragment that is attached to the end of the sentence.  The words "The ghost" are really the subject of the sentence, but have been delayed to the end and replaced by a pronoun.

So if this reading is correct, then the sentence would be normally phrased as

> Not having to work made a pleasant change.

And since the -ing word phrase is acting as the subject of the sentence you would call it a gerund.